# How to save to the database column one items that are dragged and dropped to another column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

So what I would like to do is having column one where data shown from database, and this data can be dragged and dropped to column two, finally data in column two can be save to another table in the database. The css is added so anyone can try out and understand my question. I am new to javascript so I think the problem might be somewhere in the script field.

```js
$(onPageLoad);

function onPageLoad()
{
  $( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    handle: ".portlet-header",
    cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
    start: function (event, ui) {
      ui.item.addClass('tilt');
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
      ui.item.removeClass('tilt');
    }
  });

  $( ".portlet" )
    .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
    .find( ".portlet-header" )
      .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
      .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

  $( ".portlet-toggle" ).click(function() {
    var icon = $( this );
    icon.toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick" );
    icon.closest( ".portlet" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
  });
}
function handleSaveButtonClick() {
  var dataToSave = [];
  $(".column:last-child .portlet-header").each(function() {
    var portletHeader = $(this).text();
    dataToSave.push(portletHeader);
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/workout/create",
    data: { data: dataToSave },
    success: function(response) {
      alert("Data saved successfully!");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error while saving data!");
    }
  });
  $( "#saveButton" ).click(handleSaveButtonClick);
}
```

```css
.tilt {
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
}

body {
  min-width: 520px;
}

.column {
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.portlet {
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
.portlet-header {
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}
.portlet-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.portlet-content {
  padding: 0.4em;
}
.portlet-placeholder {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Workout plan maker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="column">
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">A title</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">A description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Another title</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Another description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">One more title</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">One more description</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
</div>
<button id="saveButton">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there's php code in your html.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because even though there is php code in html, it's still working, why would it affect the code?

Comment: Ideally something like a Query wouldn't be in your HTML, but rather done in a Controller then passed to the view, but that's irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @Dave I'm not saying it's the problem, I'm saying we can't help you if you don't show us the html that gets rendered.

Comment: @TKoL That PHP is just used to render text via `{{ $workout->title }}` and `{{ $workout->description }}`; why do you think that would affect our ability to help? (benefit of the doubt if you don't know `.blade.php` syntax, which is what `@php`, `@foreach()` and `{{ }}` is)

Comment: Add controller code

Comment: If you are using `@php` in your views, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. That code belongs in your controller. There's no way to know what "the problem" is with the information you've provided here. You haven't said anything about what isn't working or what debugging you've done to figure this out. The browser inspector seems like where you should start; is a request being sent? Does it look like you'd expect?

Comment: @miken32 my bad. I am new to stackoverflow and to programming aswell. One of my problems were solved, thanks to suxgri. But looks like when I look at the dataToSave, it's empty, and also, $(".column:last-child .portlet-header").each(function(){}); won't even run at least once. Now, my plan is to get the data that is moved from the first column to the second column. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Actually, the data isn't moved, thats what I want to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the moment when you click save the ajax does not execute because the click handler of the save button is within the handleSaveButtonClick function.
try moving it outside of the function and it will work. code below

```
function handleSaveButtonClick() {
var dataToSave = [];
$(".column:last-child .portlet-header").each(function() {
  var portletHeader = $(this).text();
  dataToSave.push(portletHeader);
});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/workout/create",
  data: { data: dataToSave },
  success: function(response) {
    alert("Data saved successfully!");
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("Error while saving data!");
  }
});
//from here
}
$( "#saveButton" ).click(handleSaveButtonClick);//to here
```